# ASP parameters to call a stored procedure in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, parameters, asp-classic, ado

I try call this stored procedure in SQL Server that inserts data.

I have this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[AddUser]
   @user_id bigint,
   @user_name varchar(20)
AS
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO [users] ([id], [name]) 
   VALUES (@user_id, @user_name)
END
```

and I have this ASP code:

```
<%
Const adCmdStoredProc = 4
Const adBigInt = 20
Const adParamInput  = 1
Const adVarChar     = 200

Set conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
connectionstring = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Password=***********;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Initial Catalog=Test;Data Source=AREAWEB2-PC"
conn.Open connectionstring
Set cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
Set cmd.ActiveConnection = conn

cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
cmd.CommandText = "{call AddUser (?,?)}"

frm_id = 1
frm_name = "Carlos"

Set prmUserId = cmd.CreateParameter("@user_id", adBigInt, adParamInput, 0, frm_id)
Set prmUserName = cmd.CreateParameter("@user_name", adVarChar, adParamInput, 20, frm_name)

Cmd.Parameters.Append prmUserId
Cmd.Parameters.Append prmUserName

Set rs = cmd.Execute 


%>
```

But I get this error message:

> Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server error '80040e10'

What is wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you [Google the error code `80040e10`](https://www.google.com/search?num=100&safe=off&espv=2&q=80040e10&oq=80040e10&gs_l=serp.3..0l2j0i30l2j0i5i30l4j0i30j0i5i30.3889.4952.0.5242.3.3.0.0.0.0.124.363.0j3.3.0....0...1c.1.45.serp..0.3.361.KPLSU4BbONs) it becomes apparent quickly that the issue is one of the following to do with your parameter definitions;

> **From [Why do I get 80040E10 errors?](http://tutorials.aspfaq.com/8000xxxxx-errors/why-do-i-get-80040e10-errors.html)**
>
> ```
> Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server error '80040e10' 
> Procedure '' expects parameter '', which was not supplied.
> ```

Your issue is likely due to passing a `0` size in your `@user_id` parameter, as all parameters have to pass a maximum size either using `.CreateParameter()` or before appending a parameter to the collection using `.Size` property.

---

> **Update:**
>
> As the [OP has pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24017205/692942) the issue is actually due to the wrong `CommandType` property value being set.
>
> Thought it would be worth expanding the answer to explain why. The reason is the `CommandType` in the OP's example is set to `adCmdStoredProc` but the `.CommandText` property is not set to a Stored Procedure name, the easiest way to correct this *(instead of removing the `.CommandType`)* is to change the `.CommandText` as follows;
>
> ```vb
> cmd.CommandText = "AddUser"
> ```
>
> The other option is to change the `.CommandType` to `adCmdText` which will accept the format `{call AddUser (?,?)}`.
>
> ```vb
> cmd.CommandType = adCmdText
> ```
>
> Internally ADO uses `adCmdText` for the `adCmdStoredProc` `CommandTypeEnum` as the `.CommmandText` will get changed to the format `{call AddUser (?,?)}`, the difference is you cannot use this form yourself unless you specify `.CommandType = adCmdText`. There is no additional benefits to using either one, but in my opinion `adCmdStoredProc` just simplifies the calls and hides the nuts and bolts from you.

Answer (score -2):

The code fails because I have these incorrect:

cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc

Removing it, works.

Comment: That's because your `CommandText` doesn't contain a Stored Procedure name, which was why you get the parameter error. For that `CommandText` to work you would have to use `cmd.CommandType = adCmdText` or you could have changed `cmd.CommandText = "addUser"` and left the `CommandType` as it was.